# Using output of FindString in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask for your help again. Working on a bit of VBA that opens up a Inputbox, and finds a certain value in worksheet X, and then cuts the complete row to worksheet Y. I've completed the Inputbox/FindString-part, which is shown in; [image: this screenshot].

My question is pretty simple; How would i use the value found by the Inputbox/Findstring? With the intention on using this value to make the code that cuts the full row, and deletes the leftover space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.Copy
    Worksheet("Y").Range("A1").Paste
    Rng.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    MsgBox("Nothing found")
End If
```

Comment: Or can just use `Rng.Copy Destination: Worksheet("Y").Range("A1")`  (or something like that).

Comment: Indeed. I tend to keep operations separate, but that is just force of habit.

Comment: Gold answer. Only thing is now that i'm getting a compilation error, probably missed an END IF.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the range variable **Rng**, I would do something like this:

```
Rng.Cut
DestinationSheet.Range("destinationRange").select.Paste
```